# Is this axiom equivalent to choice over Zermelo, and is power set axiom needed for that equivalence?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is actually a fix of the axiom presented to MathStackExchange in a [prior](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096699/are-those-forms-of-choice-equivalent-in-absence-of-power-set-axiom/4096722#4096722) posting.

Lets define a binary relation predicate "chosen from" as:

$$\begin{align}C \text{ chosen from } X \iff&  \forall x \in X \, (x \cap C \neq \emptyset) \, \land \\&\neg \exists B \subsetneq C : \forall x \in X \, (x \cap B \neq \emptyset)\end{align}$$

In English: Set $C$ is chosen from set $X$ if and only if $C$ has nonempty intersection with every element of $X$ and such that no proper subset of $C$ can have nonempty intersection with every element of $X$

Define

$\begin{align} \text {Selectable} (X) \equiv_{df} & \forall x \in X \ 
  \exists y \subseteq x \\& \big{(}y \neq \emptyset \land \exists K \subseteq X \, ( y= \bigcap K) \land \\&\neg \exists L \exists z \, (z \neq \emptyset \land L  \subseteq X \land z = \bigcap L \land z \subsetneq y) \big{)}  \end{align} $

Where: $\bigcap K = \{m: K \neq \emptyset \land \forall k \in K (m \in k)\}$

In English: $X$ is Selectable if and only if of every element $x$ of $X$ there is at least a subset of $x$ that is a maximal overlap in $X$ [that is: $x$ is a nonempty intersection of some elements of $X$ but not a proper superset of a nonempty intersection of elements of $X$].  Selectable intuitively means "can be selected from its elements".

Now we stipulate the following axiom:

$\forall X \, (\text{Selectable} (X) \to \exists C: C \text{ chosen from } X) $

Now the questions are:

> Is this axiom equivalent to $\sf AC$ over the rest of axioms of Zermelo set theory?

> If yes, then is Power set axiom required to prove the equivalence of this axiom with $\sf AC$ over the rest of axioms of Zermelo set theory?

Comment: I don't understand the criteria for Selectable. For example, would a pairwise disjoint family be Selectable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I've remedied the criteria for Selectable (although even the old criteria does meet the case you mentioned), now for the new criteria, the answer is also yes, since all overlaps of multipleton subsets of $X$ are empty, and the overlap of a singleton subset of $X$ is that element itself, and that overlap is maximal in the sense that it cannot have a non empty proper subset of it that is an overlap of elements of $X$.